# issue in removing a particular attribute of a css class

Tags: jquery, css

i have a problem in removing an attribute of a CSS class applied to a html tag.I am not able to remove particular attribute of a css class applied to an HTML element from jquery.

I can able to remove color attribute of below,

```
<h3 id ="inbuild" style="color:red; text-align:left; font-size:40pt;">
    this is in-build style
</h3>
```

for which, i am using this jquery to remove the color property and its working fine.

```
$("#inbuild").prop("style").removeProperty("color");
```

but if i have the style in seperate css class, i dont know how to remove it.

```
.sampleclass
{
    color:red;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:40pt;
}

<h3 id ="external" class="sampleclass">
    this should be red with CSS property
</h3>
```

i have tried with below to remove the color attribute, but still i am not able remove it.

```
$("#reset1").on("click",
  function ()
  { 
     $("#external").prop(".sampleclass").removeProperty("color");
  }
);
```

could anyone please suggest me how to remove it?

Comment: You would have to override the `color` property or remove the class altogether.

Comment: Does setting color:inherit on .sampleClass do what you need?

Comment: i have tried with .css("color","inherit"), and its working fine... thanks for your support :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/bWTwL/1147/)

```
$("#reset1").on("click",
   function ()
   { 
     $("#inbuild").css("color","inherit");
   }
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You cant remove parts of a class. You either remove/replace the entire class or overload the specifuc style with a new value, i.e.:
`$("#external").css({color: inherit});`

Comment: thanks for the reply,' $("#external").css("color","inherit")' is working. :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("#reset1").on("click", function () { 
         $("#external").css("color","inherit");
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try inherit:

```
$(".class").css("propertyName","inherit");
```